# Easily implementable solution for this brain teaser?

Tags: algorithm

So I have a brain teaser I read on one of the algorithm and puzzle meetups we have on our uni that goes like this:

> There's a school that awards students that, during a given period, are
>   never late more than once and who don't ever happen to be absent for
>   three or more consecutive days. How many possible permutations with repetitions of
>   presence (or lack thereof) can we build for a given timeframe that
>   grant the student an award? Assume that each day is just a state
>   On-time, Late or Absent for the whole day, don't worry about specific
>   classes. Example: for three day timeframes, we can create 19 such
>   permutations with repetitions that grant an award.

I've already posted it on math.SE yesterday cause I was interested if there was some ready-bake formula we could derive to solve it but it turns out there isn't and all the transformations really are rather complex.

Thus, I'm asking here - how would you approach such a problem with an algorithm? I tried narrowing down the possibilities space but after a while taking all the possible permutations with repetitions became well too much and the algorithm started becoming really complex while I believe there should be some easy to implement way to solve it, especially since most of the puzzles we exchange on the meetup are rather like that.

Comment: Can you link the math.SE convo? Just so I won't repeat anything that's already said there.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279610/a-seemingly-easy-combinatorics-brain-teaser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of Python 3 code implementing the recursion in the answer by @ProgrammerPerson:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def count_variants(max_late, base_absent, period_length):
    """
    max_late – maximum allowed number of days the student can be late;
    base_absent – the number of consecutive days the student can be absent;
    period_length – days in a period."""

    @lru_cache(max_late * base_absent * period_length)
    def count(late, absent, days):
        if late < 0: return 0
        if absent < 0: return 0
        if days == 0: return 1
        return (count(late, base_absent, days-1) +   # Student is on time. Absent reset.
                count(late-1, base_absent, days-1) + # Student is late. Absent reset.
                count(late, absent-1, days-1))       # Student is absent.
    return count(max_late, base_absent, period_length)
```

Run example:

```
In [2]: count_variants(1, 2, 3)
Out[2]: 19
```

Comment: Your base cases are way simpler than mine. I was not sure that it will work, so hand rolled it! Plus one to you.

Answer (score 3):

This screams recursion (and/or dynamic programming)!

Suppose we try and solve a slightly general problem:

> We give an award if a student is late no more than L times, and isn't
>   absent for A or more consecutive days.

Now we want to compute the number of possibilities for an `n` days time frame.

Call this method `P(L, A, n)`

Now try to build up a recursion based on three cases for the first day of the period.

1) If the student is on-time for the first day, then the number is simply

`P(L, A, n-1)`

2) If the student is late the first day, then the number is

`P(L-1, A, n-1)`

3) If the student is absent the first day, then the number is

`P(L, A-1, n-1)`

This gives us the recursion:

> P(L, A, n) = P(L, A, n-1) + P(L-1, A, n-1) + P(L, A-1, n-1)

You can either memoize the recursion, or just have tables which you lookup.

Be careful about the base cases which are

`P(0, *, *),  P(*, 0, *) and P(*, *, 0)` and can be computed by easy mathematical formulae.

Here is quick python code, with memoization + recursion to demonstrate:

```
import math

def binom(n, r):
  return math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(r)*math.factorial(n-r))

# The memoization table.
table = {}

def P(L, A, n):

  if L == 0:
    # Only ontime or absent.
    # More absents than period.
    if A > n:
      return 2**n
    # 2^n total possibilities.
    # of that n-A+1 are non-rewarding.
    return 2**n - (n - A + 1)

  if A == 0:
    # Only Late or ontime.
    # need fewer than L+1 late.
    # This is n choose 0 + n choose 1 + ... + n choose L
    total = 0
    for l in xrange(0, min(L,n)):
      total += binom(n, l)
    return total

  if n == 0:
    return 1

  if (L, A, n) in table:
    return table[(L, A, n)]

  result = P(L, A, n-1) + P(L-1, A, n-1) + P(L, A-1, n-1)
  table[(L, A, n)] = result
  return result

print P(1, 3, 3)
```

Output is `19`.

Answer (score 2):

Let S(n) be the number of strings of length n without 3 repeated 1s.

Any such string (with length at least 3) ends in "0", "01" or "011" (and after removing the suffix, any string without three consecutive 1s can appear).

Then for n > 2, S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n-2) + S(n-3), and S(0)=1, S(1)=2, S(2)=4.

If you have a late day on day i (counting from 0), then you have S(i) ways of arranging absent days before, and S(n-i-1) ways of arranging absent days after.

Thus, the solution to the original problem is S(n) + sum(S(i)*S(n-i-1) | i = 0...n-1)

We can compute solutions iteratively like this:

```
def ways(n):
    S = [1, 2, 4] + [0] * (n-2)
    for i in xrange(3, n+1):
        S[i] = S[i-1] + S[i-2] + S[i-3]
    return S[n] + sum(S[i] * S[n-i-1] for i in xrange(n))

for i in xrange(1, 20):
    print i, ways(i)
```

Output:

```
1 3
2 8
3 19
4 43
5 94
6 200
7 418
8 861
9 1753
10 3536
11 7077
12 14071
13 27820
14 54736
15 107236
16 209305
17 407167
18 789720
19 1527607
```

Comment: Wow, that's a really great solution! One question, though - why does S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n-2) + S(n-3)? I mean - it gives us the number of strings of length n-3 for example but still we can arrange them in more than one way. How does it take thi into consideration?

Comment: @Straightfw because of the observation in the previous sentence. Or see Theorem 8.2 in "Analysis of Algorithms" by Sedgewick and Flageolet.